# Refresh core plot scatterplot

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-plot

I have a scatterplot created using Core Plot (v 1.5). The datasource is a dictionary containing (x, y, value). I like to be able to dynamically adjust how many of the (x, y) pairs to plot. However, my graphHostingView does not refresh the scatter-plot after I change the number of (x, y) pairs contained in the datasource until I resize the window. When I resize the window the new values are loaded and plotted. I have tried several solutions including:

- `[graph reloadData]`
- `[scatterplotview setNeedsDisplay:YES]`
- Forcing a call to: `[self.myScatterPlot.plotItem renderInView:self.myScatterPlot.hostingView withTheme:nil animated:NO withData:nil];`

Without success. Could anyone suggest a method that would enable my scatterplot to be dynamically updated when values change or send me a link to an example? Thanks in advance. Cheers, Trond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods available to tell a Core Plot plot that you have new data available:

- `-reloadData`: Replace all of the plot data with new data points. Calling this method on the graph causes all plots in the graph to reload their data.
- `-reloadDataInIndexRange:`: Replace the plot data in the given index range with new values leaving points outside this range untouched.
- `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:`: Insert new data points at the given index, moving the existing data points to higher indices as needed.
- `-deleteDataInIndexRange:`: Remove existing data in the given range and move existing data points to close the gap.

The "Real Time Plot" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app uses these methods to update its data. The demo uses a timer to generate random plot data but your new data can come from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eric. I studied the "Real Time Plot" example and I do get it to work now using reloadData. However, it takes about 5-10 seconds from the data I want to plot has been updated to the plot actually shows the new data (5-50 scatter points). Its almost like the plotting is paused until some trigger is reached. Do you know what this could be or if there is a way to force runloop to redraw immediately? T.

Comment: All of the methods I mentioned force the plot to redraw the next time through the Core Animation rendering cycle. Make sure that you're calling them from the main thread and that your datasource is not taking a lot of time to process the data before returning it to the plot. Any preprocessing should be done before you inform the plot (via the above methods) that new data is available.

Comment: It turned out that I called the method from a thread different from main thread. Changing to the main thread solved my problem. Thanks!